# PowerQuery Create grouped Index or Column

Tags: powerquery

[image: Example Table]

In Powerquery I have a table that has column `Text After Delim` that has numbers repeating (see attached Example Table).

I would like to create a column that groups 3 numbers with a combined index #. For example,

```
1,2,3 = 1;
4,5,6 = 2;
7,8,9 = 3;
```

and so on.

Suspecting I can do this with a formula in a custom column, but not sure how that is done. Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting this M code in your PowerQuery script (Advanced Editor)

```
#"Add new Column"= Table.AddColumn(#"Insert name previous step",
  "Desired Output", each Number.RoundUp([AantalEvents]/3,0))
```

For a calculated column in DAX that would be:

```
Desired Output = ROUNDUP([Text After Delim]/3,0)
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thank you for your input! This was exactly what I needed, except for slight change in syntax.  =Number.RoundUp([Text After Delimiter]/3,0)

Comment: Your welcome. My answer was in DAX, which wasn't what you asked for i discovered after rereading your question. Luckily the syntax is quite similar in this case. See my edit.